# What is the mathematical way of calculating PERCENT_RANK() ,CUME_DIST() ,PERCENTILE_CONT() and PERCENTILE_DISC()

Tags: sql, sql-server, math, sql-server-2012, statistics

I am trying to figure out how these newly introduced function in SQL Server Denali CTP 3 is working but didnot understood properly.

There are ofcourse some articles on [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234%28SQL.110%29.aspx) but it has not been clearly mentioned as how they are working ... in other words the maths runing behind the  scene.

Could anyone please explain that with some simple example.

I found one [here](http://beyondrelational.com/justlearned/posts/403/percentrank-and-cumedist-new-analytical-functions-in-sql-server-denali-ctp3.aspx) but when I tried to put the logic of this author in the first link for getting the Percent_Rank and Cume_Dist of 5th item I am getting  a different result.

Answer (score 7):

The columns in this query will be equal:

```
SELECT  value,
        PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value),
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN qo.value < q.value THEN 1 END) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
        FROM    mytable qo
        ) AS percent_rank_formula,
        CUME_DIST() OVER (ORDER BY value),
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN qo.value <= q.value THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable qo
        ) AS cume_dist_formula
FROM    mytable q
```

Comment: Sir,thanks for that..but I am looking after what is the maths/logic behind the calculation..Thanks

Comment: @mcUser: please look into the subqueries code and you can figure out the logic easily. `PERCENT_RANK` is the rank among the values excluding thу current one, `CUME_DIST` is that including the current one.